# How to reload element attribute inside jQuery droppable()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an inventory and every time a user deletes an item (drags it to the trash bin) I check if this item is a stack and remove 1 if it is.

The problem is that the stack number stays the same each time the user drops it

```
$('#trash-wrapper').droppable({ 

        accept: ".item", 
        drop: function(event, e){

            // If the trashed item has a stack that is bigger than 1, do not remove the element but remove 1 from the stack and return the item back
            if(e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').data('stack-count') > 1){

                var count = e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').data('stack-count');

                e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').attr('data-stack-count', (count - 1)).html(count - 1);
                _ajaxFetch("php/ajax/game/conq-delete-item.php", {dby : 'l', id: e.draggable.attr('data-loot-id')});

            }
            // Otherwise destory the element
            else{

                e.draggable.remove();
                _ajaxFetch("php/ajax/game/conq-delete-item.php", {dby : 'i', id: e.draggable.attr('data-item-id')});

            }

        }

    });
```

The problem is that Count stays always the same. If there is stack of 20, the first drop works, it changes the attribute and html to 19, but all other drops still use the count variable declared first - 20, so it never goes more than 1 below.

I even tried

```
e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').attr('data-stack-count', (e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').data('stack-count') - 1)).html(e.draggable.find('.inventory-stack').data('stack-count') - 1);
```

Doesnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

Ughhhhhh

```
data('stack-count');
```

Seems to save this globally and will not be replaced on new call

```
attr('data-stack-count');
```

Fixed it :/